# Attachments (Annotations @Step, @Screenshot) not getting saved in allure reults when running executable jar file

Tags: selenium, maven, automated-tests, testng, allure

I am a newbie software testing engineer, i had recently implemented allure reports in a testng maven project which was working fine in itself, but i was asked to make an executable .jar file so that we can can run the code without setting up the IDE, and when i run using the .jar file, the test runs fine but the screenshots and other attachments (with annotation @Step, @Attachment) donot get saved for some reason, only json files are visible in my allure-results folder. Is there something that i am missing? Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>sampleProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java.version>15</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.4</aspectj.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.automatedowl</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-environment-writer</artifactId><version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.simplejavamail/simple-java-mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.simplejavamail</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-java-mail</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.5</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>2.7.0</reportVersion>
                <resultsDirectory>${project.basedir}/allure-results/</resultsDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.4</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>MainFile.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue recently. Annotation `@Attachment` seems not to work as expected when running from jar.
Resolved it by using `Allure.addAttachment()` method. i.e:

```
Allure.addAttachment("attachmentName", yourContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Step` and `@Attachment` annotations are implemented using AspectJ. To ensure they function correctly when running the program from a jar file, you must define the AspectJ Weaver Java agent:

```
$ java -jar -javaagent:agentjweaver.jar tests.jar
```

Note: When running the program using Maven, the `argLine` configuration option of the `maven-surefire-plugin` is utilized for this purpose.